# NVIDIA GPU fan error when card is idle for a while

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, fan, nvidia

I have a supermicro server with 7 NVIDIA RTX A5000 GPUs and one L40 GPU. The OS is Ubuntu 22.04. Everything works fine, I can run jobs for serveral days without problems. However, there is a very strange problem with the A5000 cards.

When the A5000 cards are idle for a day or so, nvidia-smi shows the fan error ("ERR!") for the A5000 cards that people have asked about a couple of times already (also for other cards).
(e.g. ["Graphic card error(nvidia-smi prints "ERR!" on FAN and Usage)" and processes are not killed and gpu not being reset](https://superuser.com/questions/1459322/graphic-card-errornvidia-smi-prints-err-on-fan-and-usage-and-processes-ar))
Confusingly, in all of these questions, the problem seems to appear when the cards are actually working.
When I do a reboot, the cards are working again. This is obviously not a good solution, because  jobs on the other cards are then also stopped.

Is it possible that the GPUs are entering some sort of sleep mode when they are idle? If so, can I wake them up again?

Thank you for any suggestions.